# How to display volume slider with Chromecast icon when not using remoteMediaPlayer

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I am trying to implement the volume slider while casting and show the cast icon in the slider like in the Youtube app : https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAprv.jpg.

As of now I have overridden the dispatchKeyEvent function my activity, as explained in the cast developers documentation (shown in the code snipped below), which allows me to control the volume of the connected Chromecast perfectly. But on the device, it doesn't even show a slider at all.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
  int action = event.getAction();
  int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
  switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
      if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        if (mApiClient != null) {
          double currentVolume = Cast.CastApi.getVolume(mApiClient);
          if (currentVolume < 1.0) {
            try {
              Cast.CastApi.setVolume(mApiClient,
            Math.min(currentVolume + VOLUME_INCREMENT, 1.0));
            } catch (Exception e) {
              Log.e(TAG, "unable to set volume", e);
            }
          }
        } else {
          Log.e(TAG, "dispatchKeyEvent - volume up");
        }
      }
      return true;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
      if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        if (mApiClient != null) {
          double currentVolume = Cast.CastApi.getVolume(mApiClient);
          if (currentVolume > 0.0) {
            try {
              Cast.CastApi.setVolume(mApiClient,
            Math.max(currentVolume - VOLUME_INCREMENT, 0.0));
            } catch (Exception e) {
              Log.e(TAG, "unable to set volume", e);
            }
          }
        } else {
          Log.e(TAG, "dispatchKeyEvent - volume down");
        }
      }
      return true;
    default:
      return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
   }
  }
```

I am not using the remoteMediaPlayer. So how can I implement a volume slider while controlling the connected Chromecast volume?

Comment: Your code seems to use mRemoteMediaPlayer, so what do you mean when you say you are not using remoteMediaPlayer?

Comment: See my updated question, I copied the wrong (my old) code. Sorry about that.

Comment: Are you using RemoteControlClient at all?

Comment: So why aren't you using RemoteControlClient?

Comment: I believe you need to be using the RemoteControlClient to have a cast icon showing up when you change the volume. If you decide to use that, you can take a look at the CastCompanionLibrary that does it and the cast icon shows up when needed.

Comment: I have noticed in the [api reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteControlClient.html) that RemoteControlClient is deprecated since Lollipop, would it not be a bad idea in the long term to implement it? Should I not use the new [MediaSession](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaSession.html) class?

Comment: @RhysHalsey please share your solution if you found it. Thanks!